# How do I create aframe's component on angular 2?

Tags: angular, aframe

I have an idea to create web VR app using angular and aframe. But I can't register aframe component in angular. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

for registration you must use aframe from window, for example:

```
const aframe = (window as any).AFRAME;

ngOnInit() {
    aframe.registerComponent('elem-click', {
        init: function () {
            const el = this.el;
            el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                console.log('Hi!')
            });
        }
    });

}
```